# Find lowest value from multiple array php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm developing a number based game to calculate the combined lowest number from a multiple array.

**Example:**

```
$arr1 = array('score_1'=>0,'score_2'=>5,'score_3'=>0,'score_4'=>2,'score_5'=>1);
$arr2 = array('score_1'=>3,'score_2'=>0,'score_3'=>2,'score_4'=>0,'score_5'=>0);
$arr3 = array('score_1'=>0,'score_2'=>0,'score_3'=>0,'score_4'=>4,'score_5'=>0);
```

**The above example result will be:**

```
score_1 = 0+3+0 = 3
score_2 = 5+0+0 = 5
score_3 = 0+2+0 = 2
score_4 = 2+0+4 = 6
score_5 = 1+0+0 = 1 /*This is the winning number*/
```

Each array is a submission from each user, stored in a single db field (instead of in separate fields eg.. score_1,score_e etc...)

I'm not using separate table field because the game requires 180 score fields later. To optimize the database I'm using an array instead of table field for each score.

I'm storing each row like this:

```
score_1:0,score_2:0 etc...
```

**Later I'm looping through each row like:**

`$main_score[main_score] = $array_score[score_$key]=$value;`

**And the end result for each row:**

```
$arr1 = array('score_1'=>0,'score_2'=>5,'score_3'=>0,'score_4'=>2,'score_5'=>1);
```

How do I make the calculation?

**Explain me how am i gonna deal with this situation: Ref: below image.**
[image]

This isn't it, there are more 210 individual inputs more to go.

[Similar application](http://kubermatka.com/sp.php)

Comment: i want to store information about every row from the above mentioned form. to display a clear transaction history later on. Also if you notice each input has a different identification number on the top. starting from 128..129..120 etc. all the number are scrambled up so its not in sequence.

Comment: Submitting this one form is a single play. which means i need to track each input and its value separately when a player submit this form. I know its kind of a messy game, but that's what client wanted me to built ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should read about database normalization, then if you normalize your database, it isn't important if you store 5 or 100 scores per user. Take a look at the following table schemas:

- users

  - id
  - name
- scores

  - id
  - user_id
  - score_nr
  - value

To fetch your example result from these tables, you have to use the following query:

```
SELECT `score_nr`, SUM(`value`) AS `value_sum` 
FROM `scores` GROUP BY `score_nr`
```

To fetch the `score_nr` with the smallest sum:

```
SELECT `score_nr`, SUM(`value`) AS `value_sum` 
FROM `scores` GROUP BY `score_nr` ORDER BY `value_sum` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 for confronting the problem at the core

Comment: I think the only workaround is table based solution. So I'm sticking with that :P Thanks for the effort.

Comment: please check the updated question and also the comment...

Answer (score 2):

Loop trough the arrays simultaneously and calculate the sum of them. Keep track of the smallest key and value:

```
$smallest_val = PHP_INT_MAX;
$smallest_key = '';

foreach($arr1 as $key => $val) {
    echo $key ." = ". $val ."+". $arr2[$key] ."+". $arr3[$key] ."<br />";
    $sum = $val + $arr2[$key] + $arr3[$key];
    if($sum < $smallest_val) {
        $smallest_val = $sum;
        $smallest_key = $key;
    }
}

echo "Winrar: ". $smallest_key . " with value " . $smallest_val;
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b658c32f271ddd394e17304e666468ce8bf4330b)

Comment: Very nice example thank you :)

Comment: please check the updated question and also the comment...

Answer (score 1):

i think you can make one new table on your database for scoring.

for example you have table game which `primary key by game_id`

table : scoring

```
 ------------------------------------
|id|game_id | score_no| arr  | score | 
 ------------------------------------ 
|1 |   0    | score_1 |  1   |   0   |
|2 |   0    | score_2 |  1   |   5   |
|3 |   0    | score_3 |  1   |   0   |
|4 |   0    | score_4 |  1   |   2   |
|5 |   0    | score_5 |  1   |   1   | 
|6 |   0    | score_1 |  2   |   0   |
|7 |   0    | score_2 |  2   |   5   |
|8 |   0    | score_3 |  2   |   0   |
|9 |   0    | score_4 |  2   |   2   |
|10|   0    | score_5 |  2   |   1   | 
|11|   0    | score_1 |  3   |   0   |
|12|   0    | score_2 |  3   |   5   |
|13|   0    | score_3 |  3   |   0   |
|14|   0    | score_4 |  3   |   2   |
|15|   0    | score_5 |  3   |   1   |
 ------------------------------------
```

and you can select it with query

```
SELECT score_no, SUM(`score`) AS `sum_score` FROM `scores` GROUP BY game_id, score_no
```

Comment: Im doing this currently, but now i have decided to add more 180 fields. Just looking out for an optimized solution rather than completely depending on table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your current schema, the solution with the least amount of code should be the following:

```or-tag-here
$summedScores = array_map('array_sum', array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2, $arr3));
asort($summedScores, SORT_NUMERIC);
reset($summedScores);
$winnerScoreNr = key($summedScores);
```